# Show Hide All divs with same class at once Java Script

Tags: javascript, class, html, show-hide

I'm not sure why, but it's works for me. Maybe I uploaded something wrong. [JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/DQ26M/6/)

JS Code

```
$("#toggle-content").click(function () {
    $(".otherContainers").slideToggle(500);
});

$("#closeImgPP").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().hide(500);
});

$("#closeImgPP2").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().hide(500);
});

$("#closeImgPP3").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().hide(500);
});
```

I have like 5 same divs, I close each one and for example I close only 3 out of 5 divs and when I use show/hide button it hides divs which are currently open and show divs which were hidden.

Question is how I can make show/hide button by clicking it will display everything and by clicking again hide everything, or like 2 different buttons one for showing and one for hiding

Comment: toggle is not what you want, because toggle will hide everything visible, and show everything hidden. Make two separate buttons, and in one use hide for all the elements, and in the other, show all of them.

Comment: Yep you absolutely correct, my brain doesn't work to make two separate button... It's just crush all the time (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/DQ26M/9/
you have to change your design a bit if you want to hide them all ( cause how will you show them again? )

```
$("#hide-content").click(function () {
    $(".otherContainers").hide(500);
});

$("#show-content").click(function () {
    $(".otherContainers").show(500);
});

$("#closeImgPP").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().hide(500);
});
```

edit: and maybe closeImgPP should be a class, if you want to have this close in every 'BLAHBLAH'

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.show()` and `.hide()` methods instead of `slideToggle`

Comment: jsFiddle does that automatically

Comment: I said on MY documents it works fine, I have different question

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to do so:

```
$("#toggle-content").click(function () {
    $.each($(".otherContainers"),function(){
         $(this).toggle(500);
    });
});
```

as you are using the selector by class name and in document it is multiple. so you need to apply the toggle to each one.

Comment: @DenisS have you tried its working on fiddle when i try it. check again.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle does not load jQuery. In the left corner, add a jQuery library.
Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/DQ26M/7/

Can be good to add also some `onLoad` function on your website (jsfiddle does this for you).
For example:

```
$(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle, FYI you forgot to include jquery library in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DQ26M/11

```
$("#toggle-content").click(function () {
$(".otherContainers").slideUp(500);
$(".showContent").show();
});
$(".showContent").click(function () {
    $(this).hide(); $(".otherContainers").slideDown(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btns2').on('click', function() {
$('.chos').hide();
$('#icon3').hide();
$('#icon').show();
});

$('#btns').on('click', function() {
$('.chos').show();
$('#btns2').show();
$('#icon3').show();
$('#icon').hide();
});
```

in one button you can hide show or do toggle a div or selector using class/id at same time